# Why does CPython not store results of literals as consts of the code object?

Tags: python, programming-languages, interpreter, cpython

Why does CPython compile `return {}` to creating a new `dict`, instead of just returning a constant created once at compile time?

```
>>> def f():
...     return {}
...
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
>>> f() == f()
True
>>> f() is f()
False
```

The same can be asked for functions (with possibly a different answer?):

```
>>> def f():
...     def q():
...             pass
...     return q
...
>>> f() is f()
False
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object q at 0x00000000021C88A0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)

              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.q')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (q)

  4           8 LOAD_FAST                0 (q)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object q at 0x00000000021C88A0, file "<stdin>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

It seems the code object for `q` is created as a constant in compile time - however CPython does create a new function object at runtime.

Is this likely for performance reasons? Logical reasons? Human reasons?

Comment: I can see the nightmare that follows if you mutate the object that's returned, and it reflects across all references. This seems like a horrid idea for a programmer to have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Python semantics **requires** for `{}` to create a new fresh empty dictionary each time it is evaluated. In other words

```
def f():
    return {}

a = f()
b = f()
print(a is b)  # MUST return False
a["x"] = 1
print(b["x"])  # MUST give an error
```

The same is not true for tuples of constants, where identity is not guaranteed... for example the code

```
def g():
    return (1, 2)

import dis
dis.dis(g)
```

gives

```
 2   0 LOAD_CONST       1 ((1, 2))
     2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Of course... silly of me not to think of this - some objects are mutable. Well, I'm off to fixing my own language :P Thanks! Will accept.